# Scroll programmatically to last column in table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in a table which has horizontal scrolling, how can one best jump to the last column without adding a specific ID/class/ref to the last column itself?

E.g. I can do:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('makeStyles-tableCell-251')[document.getElementsByClassName('makeStyles-tableCell-251').length -1].scrollIntoView()
```

but instead I'd like to reference only the table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there. Try using the `:last-child` selector.

```
document.querySelector('#table-you-want tbody tr:last-child').scrollIntoView()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css psuedo selector [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) for getting the last element.

```js
document.querySelector('table tr td:last-child').scrollIntoView()
```

```css
table tr td {
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <tr>
    <td>column 1</td>
    <td>column 2</td>
    <td>column 3</td>
    <td>column 4</td>
    <td>column 5</td>
    <td>column 6</td>
    <td>column 7</td>
    <td>column 8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```